# Reference previous rows (lag of 4)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sample data containing 4 columns (qtrs,y, c1372, c5244) that are quarterly data:

[image]

I would like to convert columns c1372 and c5244 in Year-over-Year growth values of the existing values.  This requires dividing current row by current row / current row lag 4 -1.

```
update temp_09.Y_PZZA       
set C1372 = C1372 / LAG(C1372,4) - 1, 
C5244 = C5244 / LAG(C5244,4) - 1,
```

However the above solution does not work.  I receive this error:

```
[42803] ERROR: cannot use aggregate function in UPDATE
```

Also I'm not certain if the lag function is the simplest or most robust solution.  Also keep in mind that the first 4 rows cannot reference any earlier rows.  It is fine if these first 4 row values do not change.

Comment: Please show only relevant rows and use something like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ in order to show data as text instead of an image.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff.  Your comments are always helpful for rookies like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting an `update` query with a `from`, something like this:

```
update temp_09.Y_PZZA t
    set c1372 = tt.new1372,
        C5244 = tt.new_C5244
    from (select t.*,
                 C1372 / LAG(C1372, 4) over (order by qtrs)  - 1 as new_c1372,
                 C5244 / LAG(C5244, 4) over (order by qtrs) - 1 as new_C5244 
          from temp_09.Y_PZZA t
         ) tt
     where tt.qtrs = t.qtrs;
```

I wouldn't recommend overwriting the current values.  They appear to mean something.  Instead, just add another column.  In fact, you can do what you want with a view.

I suspect you have other errors in your query.  Your version should be returning an error more like this:

> 42809: window function lag requires an OVER clause

You have no aggregation functions in your code snippet.

If this is the case, I would recommend that you ask *another* question.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff this seems like it should be right, but it returns [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "t" Position: 23

Comment: @ZJAY . . . That is strange.  `UPDATE` allows table aliases.  You can remove it and use the table name for references.  Might you be using a really old version of Postgres?

Comment: Got it @Gordon Linoff, after removing table alias, it worked.  You are a SQL god!  Than you so much, I've learned so much from you over the years.  Let me know if there is anyway I can return the favor.